# Web API Design decision: Better pass model to Service method as parameter or have the model in service?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating a web API method that calls a service as follows:

```
public class AlertsController : ApiController
{ 

    IAlertsService _alertsService;
    public AlertsController(IAlertsService alertsService)
    {
        _alertsService = alertsService;
    }        

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Save(AlertModel alertModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var alert = _alertsService.SaveAlert(alertModel);
            if (alert != null)
            {
                return Ok(alert);
            }
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
 }
```

As you can see, I'm passing to the *SaveAlert* method the alertModel.

Do you think it would be better to have this code instead?

```
 public class AlertsController : ApiController
 { 
   IAlertsService _alertsService;
    public AlertsController(IAlertsService alertsService)
    {
        _alertsService = alertsService;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Save(AlertModel alertModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

          _alertService.Alert = alertModel; // so have the model defined in 
             // service layer
             var alert = _alertsService.SaveAlert();
            if (alert != null)
            {
                return Ok(alert);
            }
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Some other people prefer to implement Save method under the model, so to have 
alertModel.Save() , but I would keep the model simply empty.
What do you think it would be a better solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to define the model property in service. what if your service contains more than 100's or 1000's model and method to save entity? so better you pass the model in service method and implement your business logic.